# create heatmap2d from txt file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gnuplot, histogram

I have set of 2d data (30K) as txt file.

```
  X       Y
2.50    135.89
2.50    135.06
2.50    110.85
2.50    140.92
2.50    157.53
2.50    114.61
2.50    119.53
2.50    154.14
2.50    136.48
2.51    176.85
2.51    147.19
2.51    115.59
2.51    144.57
2.51    148.34
2.51    136.73
2.51    118.89
2.51    145.73
2.51    131.43
2.51    118.17
2.51    149.68
2.51    132.33
```

I plotted as a scatter plot with gnuplot but  I would like to represent as a heatmap2d or density distribution.
I looked through the examples in MatPlotLib or R and they all seem to already start with random data to generate the image.

I tried those code and get error like this

> hist, edges = histogramdd([x,y], bins, range, normed, weights)
>
> AttributeError: The dimension of bins must be equal to the dimension of the sample x.
> Script terminated.

Is there any methods to open txt file and plot this data in gnuplot, matplotlib.
my scatter plot look like this
[image]

i want to show this picture as contour map or density map with color code bar.
my x-axis at range of 2.5-3.5
and y axis at range of 110-180
i have 30k data points

Comment: You can't create the density distribution in `gnuplot` itself, that is possible only in 1D using `smooth kdensity`. If you want to plot the data with gnuplot you must use some other tool (e.g. Python) to preprocess the data.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to do everything in Python, you can compute the histogram and build a contour plot in one script :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the data
M = np.loadtxt('datafile.dat', skiprows=1)

# compute 2d histogram
bins_x = 100
bins_y = 100
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(M[:,0], M[:,1], [bins_x, bins_y])

# xedges and yedges are each length 101 -- here we average
# the left and right edges of each bin
X, Y = np.meshgrid((xedges[1:] + xedges[:-1]) / 2,
                   (yedges[1:] + yedges[:-1]) / 2)

# make the plot, using a "jet" colormap for colors
plt.contourf(X, Y, H, cmap='jet')

plt.show()  # or plt.savefig('contours.pdf')
```

I just made up some test data composed of 2 Gaussians and got this result :

[image: contour plot from 2d histogram]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could do it with Python preprocessing and plotting with gnuplot.

#### Variant 1

The first variant works with gnuplot's `pm3d` plotting style. This gives allows nice interpolation of the histogram data, so that the image looks smoother. But may give problems for large data sets, also depending on the output image format (see Variant 2).

The Python script `process.py` uses `numpy.histogram2d` to generate the histogram, the output is saved as gnuplot's `nonuniform matrix` format.

```
# process.py
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import sys

M = np.loadtxt('datafile.dat', skiprows=1)
bins_x = 100
bins_y = 100
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(M[:,0], M[:,1], [bins_x, bins_y])

# output as 'nonuniform matrix' format, see gnuplot doc.
print(bins_x, end=' ')
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, xedges, newline=' ')
print()

for i in range(0, bins_y):
    print(yedges[i], end=' ')
    np.savetxt(sys.stdout, H[:,i], newline=' ')
    print(H[-1,i])

# print the last line twice, then 'pm3d corners2color' works correctly
print(yedges[-1], end=' ')
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, H[:,-1], newline=' ')
print(H[-1,-1])
```

To plot, just run the following gnuplot script:

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
set xtics out
set ytics out
set pm3d map interpolate 2,2 corners2color c1
splot '< python process.py' nonuniform matrix t ''
```

#### Variant 2

The second variant works with the `image` plotting style, which may be suitable for large data sets (large histogram size), but doesn't look good e.g. for `100x100` matrix:

```
# process2.py
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import sys

M = np.loadtxt('datafile.dat', skiprows=1)
bins_x = 100
bins_y = 200
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(M[:,0], M[:,1], [bins_x, bins_y])

# remap xedges and yedges to contain the bin center coordinates
xedges = xedges[:-1] + 0.5*(xedges[1] - xedges[0])
yedges = yedges[:-1] + 0.5*(yedges[1] - yedges[0])

# output as 'nonuniform matrix' format, see gnuplot doc.
print(bins_x, end=' ')
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, xedges, newline=' ')
print()

for i in range(0, bins_y):
    print(yedges[i], end=' ')
    np.savetxt(sys.stdout, H[:,i], newline=' ')
    print()
```

To plot, just run the following gnuplot script:

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test2.png'
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
set xtics out
set ytics out
plot '< python process2.py' nonuniform matrix with image t ''
```

There might be some parts to improve (especially in the Python script), but it should work. I don't post a result image, because it looks ugly with the few data points you showed `;)`.

Comment: This script is working but it gives scatter plot not density or histogram2d.

Comment: I want to make a contour map from histogram2d.

Comment: No, the script gives a density plot. What is it in your opinion, what makes the histogram generated with `process.py` a scatter plot and not a histogram? And a contour map is something quite different from a heat map. Do you want only the contours to be plotted, or also the surface, or something else? Maybe you should post an example image, or URL showing what you really want...

Comment: the above script is run with python.

Comment: Sorry, but you are messing all up! Is your answer supposed to be a real answer? Then please put the code into the answer, and not as comment. Or is it another editing of you question? And you should get quite the same result with my gnuplot script. If not, please upload the complete data file somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, for messing all. I am using this site first time.
i edited my question. I made a scatter plat with my data but i want to show it by density map with different color.
i am trying to give my data file.

Comment: Well, you can clean it up. Either edit your answer (include the code from the comment and delete the comment) or delete your answer and include the image/code in your question, whatever seems appropriate to you. BTW: I edited my answer and added a version which works with `pm3d`, which allows interpolation of the histogram and comes to closer what you probably expected. Note, that also the Python scripts differ and were changed. So save them again to test. I'm sure, that "Variant 1" gives you an image like [the one you posted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo6bf.png), but with correct labels.