# 2D Colour plot of 3 data columns in python

Tags: python, function, plot, 2d

I've got the following problem. I'm in astrophysics, and trying to make a skymap. The collected data tells me the temperature of the sky at every (x,y)-coordinate. I've been looking for ages on how to plot this, but the best I've come up with so far is using meshgrid. My problem, however, is that this works perfectly if Z is some function of X and Y. This is not the case here; there just corresponds one temperature to every (x,y) combination. What I've been trying (clearly to no success, with some 'fake data' to test):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xw = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
yw = [20,30,40,50,60]
zw = [-10,-20,-30,-40,-50]

#Z=np.array((xw,yw,zw))
X,Y=np.meshgrid(xw,yw)
Z = X*Y
im = plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Format of the input, in a .txt file:

x1 y1 T_11

x2 y1 T_21

x3 y1 T_31

...

xn y1 T_n1

x1 y2 T_12

x2 y2 T_22

x3 y2 T_32

etc.

Any help would be very much appreciated :-)

Comment: I don't understand. You've got the data for all the combinations in your text file. In your code example, what corresponds to the `T_` readings?

Comment: I do not understand the question being asked here. The code you have given creates a plot. It is unclear what is wrong with this result.

Comment: I've been trying this with 'randomly' made X, Y and Z. So Z would correspond to T_ (but it's obviously not working). 

The problem is that this indeed gives a plot, but not anything I'm looking for. Here, I've arbitrarily made Z a function of X and Y, which is not the case in my data. Rather, I'm trying to make a plot of (x,y,z), where all three variables are read in from a file. Any idea's? :)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18552342/2604213) for a possible way to plot scattered data as heatmap.

Comment: Thanks Christoph - but that gives me a 2D histogram of 2D data (meaning the color-pattern comes from multiple occurrences of the same (x,y) combination). I'm looking for an (x,y,z) plot, where every (x,y) only occurs once, and I want to plot the corresponding z

Comment: Are the (x,y) coordinates random? If so, I don't see what you're going to do about coordinates you don't have data for. If they're not random, then surely you can make a 2D grid that can be used `pcolor` or `colorbar`. Do you have some sample data you can give?

Comment: They're not random, and every coordinate (exists and) has a temperature. It's latitude and longitude, where it counts down from (180,90,T1) (179,90,T2) (178,90,T3) ... (180,89,T4) (179,89,T5) ... (-180, -90, T6)

Answer (score 0):

```
# make a dict of x-y coords mapping to z values
skymap = {}
for x,y,z in zip(xw,yw,zw):
    skymap[(x,y)] = z

# define a function of x and y that returns the corresponding z value
# (or some default - probably not 0, more like some function of nearest
# defined (x,y) neighbors)
def getZ(x,y):
    return skymap.get((x,y), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, that definitely gets me a lot further! However; if I try this, I get an error:  


  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>

    ZZ = getZ(X,Y)

  File "test.py", line 21, in getZ

    return skymap.get((x,y), 0)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

What I tried is:
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(xw,yw)
    ZZ = getZ(X,Y)

If I try the same with ZZ = getZ(2,20) with fake arrays, that does give me the correct value. I don't get however why it doesn't work with getZ(X,Y) in general.

Comment: np.meshgrid is apparently not returning nice clean ints, but numpy.ndarrays. Before calling `getZ`, try something like `X,Y=X[0],Y[0]` - I am not a numpy expert, just a guess.

Comment: I've tried that, but that still gives me the same error. Plus, I would expect that would give some issues with plotting, as it doesn't see the nice meshgrid anymore. Any idea's? Can be using whatever method - so far I've just been using meshgrid as it got me the furthers, but that's definitely not a requirement. Anything that gets me there would be awesome!

Comment: Go read the numpy API, find out how to extract X and Y as integers from the tuple returned by meshgrid, and do this in `getZ` just before calling `skymap.get`.