# How can I represent accurately an adjacency matrix of a big graph on a small image with gnuplot?

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I am trying to create an adjacency matrix of a graph with gnuplot. The input graph has much more nodes than the pixels of the image that I will create. So, even for very sparse graphs I get very dark images.

My script is the following:

```
set terminal png size 800,800
set output "output.png"
set xrange []
set yrange [] reverse
set format y ""
set format x ""
unset xtics
unset x2tics
unset ytics
unset y2tics
plot 'data.dat' using 2:1 with dots lc rgb "#000000" notitle
```

I have thought of using 'every' to take a sample of the graph but I am not sure how I can choose an appropriate step. Using nodes/pixels for step creates a graph sparser than what I expected. Another idea is to use a heat map with colors making up for the shortage of pixels. However, I am not aware of how to create a heat map with gnuplot, since all the examples I find online seem to use a matrix for input while I use points for plotting.

Can someone provide me with an example for a heat map with points instead of a matrix as input or justify which step would be appropriate for use in order to get a good representation?

Comment: For the coloring you need additional information, i.e. bin your data: create a regular grid (e.g. 100 x 100) and count how many nodes are inside each bin. The you can plot this matrix (row, col, count). The binning can't be done inside gnuplot, see [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18528908/2604213](create heatmap2d from txt file) for two possibilities of doing this on-the-fly with python.

Comment: You might use a vector format, e.g. eps or pdf, with very thin lines/points, which could create images with "infinitely" zoomable detail.

Comment: I want to use the final image in a hard copy so the vector format is not a solution I am afraid