# Gnuplot 2D Scatter Plot Density

Tags: gnuplot

What I'm trying to achieve seems trivial, and yet I can't get around making it work.

I have a two column data-set, which I can plot just. Problem is, some region have too high a point density, so after a certain threshold adding point does not change the visual rendering. What I would like is cut the surface in small square, count the number of points in each small square and draw a colored square with a palette reflecting the point density in this particular square.

Yet, I can't think of a mixing of the words 'gnuplot', 'palette', 'contour plot', '2D density' that will yield something answering my question (all I can find are `splot` related).

Comment: You must use an external tool to do the binning of you data, then you can use `plot ... with image` or `set pm3d map; splot ... ` to create the actual plot. See if the answers to [create heatmap2d from txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526485/create-heatmap2d-from-txt-file) do help you.

Comment: @Christoph Hey, That definitly worked ! You should answer the question with it so that I can accept it ;)

Comment: I'll vote for closing your question as duplicate, that's how it should be handled. But feel free to vote on the other answer :)