# Making eye-diagram with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, diagram, alpha-transparency, curves

I would like to plot 1000+ curves and display their eye diagram with gnuplot.

Example of eye-diagram example with matlab: http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/comm/ref/commscope.eyediagram.html

I can already plot the curves using the script bellow:

```
gnuplot> plot for [col=1:1000] 'input_dataset1.txt' using 0:col with lines linecolor rgb("#0000ff")
```

Result: [output_image.png](http://i60.tinypic.com/5ev2nc.png)
My problem is that when two lines intersects, the intersection has the same color as the line. The eye-diagram should display area with lots of intersections in a different color.

I haven't fould any example of such diagrams made with gnuplot.

Playing with line transparency didn't work: the intersction of two semi-transparent lines is the same color as the line.

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want a 2D plot of your data?  If so then look into the `splot` command or `plot 'data.txt' matrix with image'.  I ask because an eye diagram looks just like a specific use for a 2D plot.

Comment: For this you must create a histogram with an external tool, see e.g. [create heatmap2d from txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526485/create-heatmap2d-from-txt-file).

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a gnuplot-only way to do this, it involves a bit of work and you'll probably have to fine tune the details for your particular problem.

As an example I generated a data file containing values for the function `exp(x)` and its Taylor expansions from order zero (`T^(0)[exp(x)] = 1`) to order 3 (`T^(3)[exp(x)] = 1 + x + x**2/2. + x**3/6.`). This kind of data is suited to this problem because you will have a high data density around the origin, where all the approximations converge to the exact value, and lower data density away from it. It can be generated like this with gnuplot:

```
set xrange [0:1]
set table
set output "| grep -v '^$' > data"
plot exp(x), 1, 1+x, 1+x+x**2/2., 1+x+x**2/2.+x**3/6.
unset table ; unset output
```

Note I'm formatting the output so my data file has no blank lines, otherwise gnuplot treats fields separated by blank lines as different data blocks and this eventually messes up the histograms below. This data looks like this (`plot "data"`):

[image]

Now, I create a 2D histogram with this data. It would be extremely helpful if gnuplot offered this feature, but it doesn't, so the task gets a bit tricky. What I will do is create several 1D histograms. For more info on how to generate the latter, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471884/histogram-using-gnuplot).

The first thing is to figure out the width along `x` and `y` for your bins, `xwidth` and `ywidth`, where the number of data points are counted, that is, we divide the data space into a grid where each element measures `xwidth` by `ywidth` and is assigned a number equal to the number of data points contained within. The smaller these elements the better resolution your graph will have, but also the more data points you'll need for it to look good. For my data above, this could be something like

```
xwidth = 0.02
ywidth = 0.05
```

Now we declare a function to define our 1D bins ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471884/histogram-using-gnuplot)):

```
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0
```

and define the number of bins along each direction. Because the `xrange` for my data is `[0:1]` and my `yrange` is [1:2.8], the number of bins would be 50 and 36, respectively. I could use `Nx = xrange / xwidth` but that would lead to a float `Nx` and I want an integer. To be safe I do:

```
Nx = 50
Ny = 36
```

It might make more sense to define these values the other way around: calculate `xwidth` as `xrange / Nx`, in which case you should not have problems with integer/float.

Now I generate the 1D histograms along `y`, looping over `x` values:

```
set output "| grep -v 'u\\|^$' | sed 's/#/\\n#/g' > data2"
set table
plot for [i=0:(Nx-1)] "./data" using \
(bin($2,ywidth)):( i*xwidth <= $1 && (i+1.)*xwidth > $1 ? 1.0 : 0.0) \
smooth freq
unset table ; unset output
```

Now `data2` contains `Nx` blocks of data, each of them being a scan along `y` with `Ny` data points. The value of these data points is the number of data entries in the original `data` file. As it is, `data2` contains 2D data (`y`, `color`), which I need to remap to 3D. The `x` value is given by the data block position, accessible with the `every` option in gnuplot. To plot this 3-dimensionally I do:

```
set output "| grep -v 'u\\|^$' | sed 's/#/\\n#/g' > data3"
set table
splot for [i=0:(Nx-1)] "./data2" every :::i::i using \
((i+0.5)*xwidth):1:2
unset table ; unset output
```

This `data3` can now be plotted as a color map:

```
plot "./data3" with image
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Had I used higher quality data (i.e. with higher resolution) the graph would look nicer. With 2x resolution along each direction, the same looks like below:

[image]