# Prepare XY coordinate data for heatmap in GnuPlot

Tags: statistics, 2d, coordinates, gnuplot, heatmap

I am currently trying to create a heatmap in Gnuplot from a set of coordinates I gather from a users travels through a 3d world. I would like to see how people's navigation through the 3d world changes depending on various factors.

Most questions, answers, tutorials and information I've found online for creating heatmaps in Gnuplot assume that you have 3 variables. X, y and z (heat/density). But in my case I only have two (x and Y) and the heat/color would be defined by the amount of points on the same/similar coordinate.

To put it short, how can I prepare the data for something like the gnuplot example heatmaps. http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html

Below is some test data I gathered through a short playthrough.

```
x,y
0.000000,1.708877
-0.5320375,1.70922
-0.9563416,1.708709
-3.279445,1.680813
-8.411119,1.519087
-12.69817,1.495463
-9.760756,1.490492
-6.663352,1.564445
-5.626318,1.981441
-6.706789,2.282912
-7.388122,2.138686
-7.934381,2.181237
-8.476064,1.887571
-8.194725,1.707885
-8.535669,2.444625
-9.646641,2.041552
-10.44892,1.795496
-11.22491,1.652639
-12.00315,1.357903
-12.78364,1.404106
-13.59802,1.178438
-14.4347,1.314996
-15.33126,1.49497
-16.23087,1.514813
-16.65135,1.542829
-15.86543,1.671485
-16.45247,1.794773
-17.04028,1.782544
-15.1876,2.019355
-14.77634,1.227442
-14.82334,1.07369
-12.69955,1.048215
-12.21718,1.083204
-13.46084,1.073263
-14.34087,1.226613
-14.47059,1.141484
-12.96677,1.118232
-12.45283,1.082508
-12.29562,1.185747
-16.07011,1.076728
-13.87763,1.110883
-16.23921,1.124403
-14.01696,1.052705
-15.13995,1.967102
-13.81338,2.316191
-12.68139,2.668352
-11.77261,1.047897
-11.4139,1.050000
```

Comment: See my answer to [create heatmap2d from txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18528908/2604213) and use `M = np.loadtxt('scatter.txt', skiprows=1, delimiter=',')` to read in the comma-delimited data. I got the result http://i.stack.imgur.com/wsuMC.png which looks good to me

Comment: Sorry about late reply. (was without internet for almost 2 weeks) That did the trick! thank you very much.